# Issue with import statement file paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

When I attempt to import my SearchBar component into App.js, it says that the module cannot be resolved.

I've been trying to figure this out for days so I assume I must be making a some kind of syntax error.

I've tried just using an export statement on the class declaration line for the SearchBar component class and then importing it into App.js using: `Import { SearchBar } from './Components/SearchBar/Searchbar;'`

Here is the code for SearchBar.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import './SearchBar.css';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(<JSX Elmements>)
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Here is the import statement in App.js:

```
import SearchBar from './Components/SearchBar/SearchBar';
```

And this is the file structure:

```
SRC/
- App.js
- App.css
- Components/
  - SearchBar/
    - SearchBar.js
    - SearchBar.css
```

This is the error message I get:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './Components/Searchbar/SearchBar' in '/home/runner/src'
```

Comment: What are you using to transpile your code?

Comment: Originally I was just running it on node.js to a local port. I had so much trouble getting the imports to work that I recreated the project in Repl.it. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first `SearchBar` (directory) in your import has a lowercase `b`.

In your directory structure they are all `CamelCase`.

So it should be

```
import SearchBar from './Components/SearchBar/SearchBar';
```

here was the typo -------------------------------------------^

Comment: Hey, that was a typo from when I was posting the question. The B is capitalized in my code. I'll edit it in this post

Comment: Ah okay, too bad ;) Maby you can reproduce it with a code sample like `codesandbox.io`?